# Access samba share from other linux client

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

First of all, I'm a long-time Windows user and thought I should try something new. So be easy on me and pardon in ahead if I don't get all that linux mumble-jumble ;)

So I installed a Ubuntu Server and started to create samba shares. I wanted one share public accessible without password and one share that required password.

The password less share is all fine, but the password-protected share is not working as fine. When I try to browse the share from a Windows client I get a login window and enter the username and password. That's all working great.

But when I try to access the same shared folder from a Linux client and enter username and password it seems as it's the wrong password. Just keep getting the credentials windows thrown in my face.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the user you are trying to connect with to the smbusers file? If not try this. It helped me with exactly the same issue:

Open a terminal and type the following command:

`sudo smbpasswd -a username`

After that, you should be able to use that username and password on the windows pc to connect to the share you created.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Since it works from Windows clients but not linux clients i don't think there is something wrong with the samba user and password.